# How to create MySQL friendly view from a query result

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a *friendly view from MySQL query results* like this image's examples to propose questions here, at stackoverflow, that are relationated with MySQL database problems.

I don't even know if *friendly view* is the correct term for this. But every time that I have to show my mysql table's data, I draw this information manualy.

I do something like this:

```
id_auto | name | type
1, john, person
```

I would like to do like the following **examples:**

[image]

[image]

- I know this is a dumb question, but a search a lot and couldn't find any answer for this. Basically, I would like to produce data sample in this example's format from my pre existing mysql tables.

Comment: your question  is  too broad  .. try explain better  your goal

Comment: Some more information is required as to the environment you are trying to get the output in. I'm guessing that you are referring to command line interface as opposed to anything else.

Comment: @scaisEdge, I will edit my question.

Comment: @JimGrant I've updated my question. It's so simple that is complex to explain. ehehehe

Comment: @scaisEdge done!

Comment: you are asking for a way to produce data sample  for stackoverflow as text  ???

Comment: @scaisEdge yes. How to produce data sample from my pre existing mysql tables.

Comment: You can use a sqlfiddle and (however) copy the table sample as text .. or use a sql IDE as TOAD for mySql or  mysql workbench  and also from these copy your table data as sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the MySQL website.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-output-table-format.html

**5.6.1 Table Format**

The table format is used by default for printing result sets when MySQL Shell is in interactive mode. The results of the query are presented as a formatted table for a better view and to aid analysis.

To get this output format when running in batch mode, start MySQL Shell with the `--result-format=table` command line option (or its alias `--table`), or set the MySQL Shell configuration option resultFormat to table.

```
mysql-sql> select * from sakila.actor limit 3;
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+
| actor_id | first_name  | last_name      | last_update          |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE    | GUINESS        | 2006-02-15 4:34:33   |
|        2 | NICK        | WAHLBERG       | 2006-02-15 4:34:33   |
|        3 | ED          | CHASE          | 2006-02-15 4:34:33   |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Yes! This is it! So the correct term is "Table format".  My question was difficult to understand?